# On a determinantal equality

Tags: co.combinatorics, matrices, determinants

In my study, I come across the following curious equality, which I do not know a proof yet (so I am asking it here).

Let $k$, $l\in \Bbb Z$ be fixed, $m$ --- the size of the below matrix $M$ --- is also fixed, and let $a_i$ be independent variables. 
We define $M$ by the formula: the $(i,j)$-th entry of $M$ is $a_{ik+jl}$.

Example: $k=1$, $l=2$, $m=3$, we have

$M= \left( \begin{array} {a} a_3 & a_5 & a_7 \\ a_4 & a_6 & a_8 \\ a_5 & a_7 & a_9\end{array} \right)$

Let, further, a sequence of integer numbers $\lambda=(c_1, \dots, c_m)$ be fixed. We denote by $S$ the set of all permutations of $c_1, \dots, c_m$ (the cardinality of $S$ 
can be less than $m!$, because some of $c_i$ can be equal).

Let $\sigma=(d_1,\dots, d_m)$ be an element of $S$. We define a matrix $M_{r,\sigma}$ ($r$ means rows) 
as follows: its $(i,j)$-th entry is $a_{ik+jl+d_i}$, i.e. the indices of all $a_*$ of the first row of $M$ are increased at $d_1$, the indices of all $a_*$ of 
the second row of $M$ are increased at $d_2$, etc.

Analogically, we define a matrix $M_{c,\sigma}$ ($c$ means columns) 
as follows: its $(i,j)$-th entry is $a_{ik+jl+d_j}$, i.e. the indices of all $a_*$ of the first column of $M$ are increased at $d_1$, the indices of all $a_*$ of 
the second column of $M$ are increased at $d_2$, etc.

Example: let $\lambda=(1,0,0)$. We have: $S$ consists of 3 elements $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, $(0,0,1)$. For example, for $\sigma=(0,1,0)$ we have $M_{c,\sigma}=\left( \begin{array} {a}
a_3 & a_6 & a_7 \\ a_4 & a_7 & a_8 \\ a_5 & a_8 & a_9\end{array} \right)$. (the indices of $a_*$ of the second column increase at 1, the indices of $a_*$ of the first and third columns remain the same).

Proposition. For all $k$, $l$, $m$, $\lambda$ we have 
$$\sum_{\sigma\in S} |M_{r,\sigma}| = \sum_{\sigma\in S} |M_{c,\sigma}|$$

Example. For the above $k$, $l$, $m$, $\lambda$ we have: matrices $M_{r,\sigma}$ have two equal rows for $\sigma=(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, hence the corresponding determinants are 0, and 
for this case the proposition becomes:

$$\left| \begin{array} {a}a_3 & a_5 & a_7 \\ a_4 & a_6 & a_8 \\ a_6 & a_8 & a_{10} \end{array} \right| = \left| \begin{array} {a} a_4 & a_5 & a_7 \\ a_5 & a_6 & a_8 \\ a_6 & a_7 & a_9\end{array} \right| +\left| \begin{array} {a} a_3 & a_6 & a_7 \\ a_4 & a_7 & a_8 \\ a_5 & a_8 & a_9\end{array} \right| + 
\left| \begin{array} {a} a_3 & a_5 & a_8 \\ a_4 & a_6 & a_9 \\ a_5 & a_7 & a_{10}\end{array} \right| $$

Question. 1. Is the proposition really true for all $k$, $l$, $m$, $\lambda$? Maybe they must satisfy some conditions?

2. Is it already known, what is a reference?

Origin of the question: Resultantal varieties related to zeroes of L-functions of Carlitz modules http://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.2900.pdf

Comment: Nice question! The answer to 1 is "yes", and you can even replace the $a_{ik+jl+r}$ by the less awkward $b_{i,j,r}$, where $\left(b_{i,j,r}\right)$ is a family indexed by three integers. I'll write up a proof shortly. No idea about 2, but I remember seeing something remotely similar in Muir's 5-volume history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me prove a slightly more general claim.

> **Theorem 1.** Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a commutative ring. Let $R$ be a set. Let
>   $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (where $\mathbb{N}=\left\{  0,1,2,\ldots\right\}  $). Set
>   $\left[  n\right]  =\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $. For every $i\in\left[
> n\right]  $, $j\in\left[  n\right]  $ and $r\in R$, let $b_{i,j,r}$ be an
>   element of $\mathbb{K}$.
>
> Let $t\in R^{n}$ be an $n$-tuple of elements of $R$. Let $T$ be the set of
>   all permutations of this $n$-tuple $t$. For every $n$-tuple $d\in R^{n}$ and
>   every $i\in\left[  n\right]  $, we shall write $d_{i}$ for the $i$-th entry of
>   $d$ (so that $d=\left(  d_{1},d_{2},\ldots,d_{n}\right)  $). Then,
>
> $\sum\limits_{d\in T}\det\left(  \left(  b_{i,j,d_{i}}\right)  _{1\leq i\leq
> n,\ 1\leq j\leq n}\right)  =\sum\limits_{d\in T}\det\left(  \left(  b_{i,j,d_{j}
> }\right)  _{1\leq i\leq n,\ 1\leq j\leq n}\right)  $.

This Theorem generalizes your statement (namely, it suffices to apply it to
$b_{i,j,r}=a_{ik+jl+r}$). Actually, it does not take it very far, as it can in
turn be derived from it by setting $k$ and $l/k$ large enough; however, it is
the kind of generalization that is worth making even if you do not need the
generality, as it pulls things apart that don't belong together.

*Proof of Theorem 1.* We let $S_{n}$ denote the symmetric group on $n$
elements (i.e., the group of all permutations of $\left[  n\right]  $). For
every $\tau\in S_{n}$, we let $\left(  -1\right)  ^{\tau}$ denote the signum
of $\tau$. For every $d\in T$, we have

$\det\left(  \left(  b_{i,j,d_{i}}\right)  _{1\leq i\leq n,\ 1\leq j\leq
n}\right)  =\sum\limits_{\tau\in S_{n}}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\tau}\prod\limits_{i=1}
^{n}b_{i,\tau\left(  i\right)  ,d_{\tau\left(  i\right)  }}$

(by the definition of a determinant). Summing this equation over all $d\in T$,
we obtain

$\sum\limits_{d\in T}\det\left(  \left(  b_{i,j,d_{i}}\right)  _{1\leq i\leq
n,\ 1\leq j\leq n}\right)  $

$=\sum\limits_{d\in T}\sum\limits_{\tau\in S_{n}}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\tau}\prod\limits_{i=1}
^{n}b_{i,\tau\left(  i\right)  ,d_{i}}$

**(1)** $=\sum\limits_{\tau\in S_{n}}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\tau}\sum\limits_{d\in T}
\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}b_{i,\tau\left(  i\right)  ,d_{i}}$.

On the other hand, for every $d\in T$, we have

$\det\left(  \left(  b_{i,j,d_{j}}\right)  _{1\leq i\leq n,\ 1\leq j\leq
n}\right)  =\sum\limits_{\tau\in S_{n}}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\tau}\prod\limits_{i=1}
^{n}b_{i,\tau\left(  i\right)  ,d_{\tau\left(  i\right)  }}$

(by the definition of a determinant). Summing this equation over all $d\in T$,
we obtain

$\sum\limits_{d\in T}\det\left(  \left(  b_{i,j,d_{j}}\right)  _{1\leq i\leq
n,\ 1\leq j\leq n}\right)  $

$=\sum\limits_{d\in T}\sum\limits_{\tau\in S_{n}}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\tau}\prod\limits_{i=1}
^{n}b_{i,\tau\left(  i\right)  ,d_{\tau\left(  i\right)  }}$

**(2)** $=\sum\limits_{\tau\in S_{n}}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\tau}\sum\limits_{d\in T}
\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}b_{i,\tau\left(  i\right)  ,d_{\tau\left(  i\right)  }}$.

Now, fix $\tau\in S_{n}$. The set $T$ consists of all permutations of $t$;
thus, every permutation of every $n$-tuple in $T$ will again be an $n$-tuple
in $T$. Thus, the map

$T\rightarrow T,\ d\mapsto\left(  d_{\tau\left(  1\right)  },d_{\tau\left(
2\right)  },\ldots,d_{\tau\left(  n\right)  }\right)  $

is well-defined. This map is furthermore a bijection (indeed, the inverse map
is given by $T\rightarrow T,\ d\mapsto\left(  d_{\tau^{-1}\left(  1\right)
},d_{\tau^{-1}\left(  2\right)  },\ldots,d_{\tau^{-1}\left(  n\right)
}\right)  $). Hence, we can substitute $\left(  d_{\tau\left(  1\right)
},d_{\tau\left(  2\right)  },\ldots,d_{\tau\left(  n\right)  }\right)  $ for
$d$ in the sum $\sum\limits_{d\in T}\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}b_{i,\tau\left(  i\right)  ,d_{i}
}$. As a consequence, we obtain

**(3)** $\sum\limits_{d\in T}\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}b_{i,\tau\left(  i\right)  ,d_{i}}
=\sum\limits_{d\in T}\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}b_{i,\tau\left(  i\right)  ,d_{\tau\left(
i\right)  }}$.

Now, let us forget that we fixed $\tau$. We thus have shown that **(3)** holds
for every $\tau\in S_{n}$. Now, **(1)** becomes

$\sum\limits_{d\in T}\det\left(  \left(  b_{i,j,d_{i}}\right)  _{1\leq i\leq
n,\ 1\leq j\leq n}\right)  $

$=\sum\limits_{\tau\in S_{n}}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\tau}\sum\limits_{d\in T}\prod\limits_{i=1}
^{n}b_{i,\tau\left(  i\right)  ,d_{i}}$

$=\sum\limits_{\tau\in S_{n}}\left(  -1\right)  ^{\tau}\sum\limits_{d\in T}\prod\limits_{i=1}
^{n}b_{i,\tau\left(  i\right)  ,d_{\tau\left(  i\right)  }}$ (by **(3)**)

$=\sum\limits_{d\in T}\det\left(  \left(  b_{i,j,d_{j}}\right)  _{1\leq i\leq
n,\ 1\leq j\leq n}\right)  $ (by **(2)**).

This proves Theorem 1.

Comment: Dear Prof. Grinberg, thank you for the proof. If you are interested in it I can send you a paper in progress containg an application of this theorem. This subject can be greatly developed.

Comment: Just for reference: The paper Dmitry Logachev was talking about is [Stefan Ehbauer, Dmitry Logachev, Márcia Sarraff de Nascimento, *Some cases of a conjecture on L-functions of twisted Carlitz modules*, arXiv:1707.04339v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.04339v1), published in [Communications in Algebra 2017](https://doi.org/10.1080/00927872.2017.1379085). Proposition 3.10 in this paper (both the arXiv version and the published version) is Theorem 1 in my post (more precisely, it is the particular case when all entries of $t$ are distinct; but the general case is easily derived from this).